# Show that if a normed space $X $ has a linearly independent subset of $n$ elements, so does the dual space $X'$

Tags: functional-analysis

Show that if a normed space $X $ has a linearly independent subset of $n$
elements, so does the dual space $X'$

**My attempt** :

$\text{Given that  a  normed space  $X$ has  a linearly indepenedent  susbset of  $n-$  element}\tag1$

let the subset be  $S=\{ e_1,e_2,e_3,....,e_n\}$

Define $e_i \in X$ by $f_j(e_i)= \delta_{ij} = \begin{cases} 1 & i=j \\0 , & i \neq j  \end{cases}$ where $1\le i\le n$ and $1\le j\le n$

From $(1)$ we have  $c_1e_1+...+c_ne_n=0\implies c_1f(e_1)+...+c_nf(e_n)=0$

After  that im not able to proceed further

Comment: See this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4067730/application-of-hahn-banach-theorem/4067779#4067779

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/952585/is-it-true-that-dimx-leq-dimx-ast-for-every-infinite-dimentional-ban